# Jenkins cron format

Tags: cron, jenkins

In Jenkins we have the Poll SCM schedule set to `* * * * *`.  But Jenkins suggests `Do you really mean "every minute" when you say "* * * * *"? Perhaps you meant "0 * * * *"`

Is there any difference between `* * * * *` and `0 * * * *` ?

Comment: I must have had a brain explosion when asking this question... so obvious.

Comment: Documentation page https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Of course there is a difference!

`0 * * * *` - is every hour, when minute == 0.(i.e. 1:00, 2:00,..)

`* * * * *` - is every minute

Check out the [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-cron-guide) for more info.

Comment: Updated link to guide.

Answer (score 23):

Every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)

```
H/15 * * * *
```

Every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)

```
H(0-29)/10 * * * *
```

Once every two hours at 45 minutes past the hour starting at 9:45 AM and finishing at 3:45 PM every weekday.

```
45 9-16/2 * * 1-5
```

Once in every two hours slot between 9 AM and 5 PM every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)

```
H H(9-16)/2 * * 1-5
```

Once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December

```
H H 1,15 1-11 *
```

Comment: Nice info but doesn't really relate directly to the question.

Comment: True, but i wanted to know more examples of cron expressions. So, when i searched for, this question looked most appropriate to also put this info

Comment: I've seen "@daily" in a Jenkins cron expression and I think it supports many special values like this but cannot find the list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Poll SCM will ping the Source Code which is configured in the Jenkins project and if there is any new commits from the previous build then only it will trigger the build. If you want to trigger the build by overriding this then use Build Periodically feature