# How to configure Selenium+GitHub+Jenkins

Tags: git, selenium, github, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to configure Selenium+GitHub+Jenkins, but unable to do it. I was able to configure selenium + Jenkins but not with GitHub.

***I want to run the selenium scripts when new push committed to git-hub and jenkins should execute the scripts.***

I searched over internet but I didn't get the solution.

If you required more information on this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

**If the GitHub repository is private, you'll need to specify an SSH key that your Jenkins server will connect with.**

You'll configure your project to pull down the source repository

[image: add git source]

Then you'll modify the recurrence of building.  In your case, since you want to build on push, the way I'm familiar with it, is by specifying the "Poll SCM" option in the *Build Triggers*.

[image: build triggers]

In the example above, they are basically polling GitHub, for a change, every minute.  You can learn more from another SO post on Jenkins Cron [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109443/jenkins-cron-format)

As far as running your test, there are many way you can do that, but if you are using a build system like Ant or Maven, this'll be trivial.

In the **Build Steps**, you'll Execute Top Level Maven, and specify the option. (usually `mvn test`)

Comment: I do not have private repository and I have posted my settings in this location [http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22161/how-to-configure-seleniumgithubjenkins?noredirect=1#comment25104_22161]

Comment: Adding one more point here: If you are not using Maven project the use custom "Execute windows batch command", in this you can create batch file and run.